# Function that is agnostic to object implementing len() or shape

Tags: python, function, oop

I have a function `func(x)` which expects a parameter x. x should be some kind of collection or array. `func(x)` needs to get the length of x:

```
 def func(x):        
    for i in range(len(x)):
        print('Something', i)
```

The problem is that some collection-like objects have `len()` implemented but not `.shape` (e.g. a list) others have `.shape` implemented but not `len()` (e.g. a sparse matrix). What is the most **pythonic** way to make func(x) work, regardless of this issue? Or are there other things to consider when looking for a solution for this problem?

What I can think of:

- Expecting another parameter: `func(x, length_of_x)`
- Calling a different function altogether
- Catching missing implementation with try-except:

  ```
   import numpy as np
   from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
   def func(x):
       try:
           length_of_x = len(x)
       except:
           length_of_x = x.shape[0]

       for i in range(length_of_x):
           print('Something', i)

   func([1, 2, 3])

   sparse_matrix = csr_matrix(([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], ([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])))
   func(sparse_matrix)
  ```
- if-else Block

  ```
   def func(x):
       if isinstance(x, csr_matrix):
           length_of_x = x.shape[0]
       else:
           length_of_x = len(x)   
       for i in range(length_of_x):
           print('Something', i)
  ```

Comment: Get your function to call `hasattr()`  on the object and test for `"len"` and if that does not succeed, test for `"shape"`, etc.

Comment: The concept of "length" in a matrix is… ill-defined…? That's why it's `shape` and not `len`. Does it really make sense for the function to accept either type? Maybe you want to move the iteration logic into a separate function and only put the common `print('Something', i)` logic into its own function…

Comment: IMHO, the pythonic way is try-except. It is the more tolerant to the actual class. Simply you must be aware of what it means: if `len(x)` is defined *whatever its meaning* then use it, else use `shape(x)[0]`. But I am posting it as a mere comment because it is just my *opinion* - BTW it is said *better to beg for forgiveness than to ask for permission*.

Comment: @deceze the iteration is just an example here, i need the indexes, actually

Answer (score 1):

The most Pythonic way to approach would be to build the internal logic using iterators rather than indexes.

```
def func(x):        
    for value in x:
        print('Something', value)
```

Comment: This would be `for i, value in enumerate(x)` because I need the index and the whole object, not the value, but good point!